# Value from custom field is not being displayed?

Tags: custom-field

For some reason this custom field is not being shown in the page.

This is the template file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: bbPress - Topics (Newest)
 *
 * @package bbPress
 * @subpackage Theme
 */

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php do_action( 'bbp_template_notices' ); ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div id="topics-front" class="bbp-topics-front">
                        <div class="entry-content">

                            <div id="page-intro">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'bbp_topics' ); ?>

                        </div>
                    </div><!-- #topics-front -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'note', true) ) : ?>
                    <div id="note">
                        <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'note', true); ?><p/>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see everything is set:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing it outside of The Loop there, so $post is undefined at that point. Put it above the `endwhile` and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar situation and the `global $post` solution do the trick. :)

Comment: Main template files are included in global scope, so `global $post;` is of no use here.